# Is it better to use different types of exceptions, or a single exception type with different codes?

Tags: php, exception

I currently have a class which throws only one type of exception, but with different exception codes :

```
class Foo
{
    public static function method($var)
    {
        if ($condition1) {
            throw new FooException('XXX', 'FORMAT');
        }

        if ($condition2) {
            throw new FooException('XXX', 'RANGE');
        }
        return doSomething($number);
    }
}

class FooException extends Exception
{
    public function __construct($message, $code = 'UNDEFINED_ERROR', Exception $previous = null)
    {
        $this->message  = $message;
        $this->code     = $code;
        $this->previous = $previous;
    }
}
```

Is there an important difference between this first implentation and another one where different exceptions are thrown ?

```
class Bar
{
    public static function method($var)
    {
        if ($condition1) {
            throw new BarFormatException('XXX');
        }

        if ($condition2) {
            throw new BarRangeException('XXX');
        }
        return doSomething($number);
    }
}

class BarFormatException extends Exception
{}

class BarRangeException extends Exception
{}
```

Comment: different exceptions are better since you can catch them with different error handling code to appropriately fix it.

Comment: How is it different from catching the only exception type, and making some different tasks depending on the code ?

Comment: you have to double-checkthe data inside your error-handling code, test for every possibility and handle cases where you don't handle your current exception by rethrowing it. all stuff that php does automatically by itself if you use different exception types, which results in shorter, cleaner and faster code.

Comment: Thanks ! Can you make it an answer, so I can validate it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only one exception type with additional values means you have to handle every single exception type yourself, differenciating in one single catch-block every type of error and watching out for cases you don't handle so you can rethrow them.

all of that, PHP does by itself automaticall when you use different exception types - much cleaner, faster end less prone for errors, so you don't have to worry about accidentally introducing errors into your error handling.

furthermore: custom exception types can have differing internal data, depending on what they are.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the precise explanation !